# Pandas: astype(int) converts all values to -2147483648

Tags: python, pandas

I am converting large numbers to `int` using `astype()`.

```
import pandas as pd
x = [56668772800.0, 55899926600.0, 55038007900.0, 58073681300.0, 58224458500.0]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["pol_number"])
df.pol_number = df.pol_number.astype(int)
df
```

And all five values have become -2147483648.

I assume the numbers are too big for type `int` but `long int` and `big int` don't compile.

Comment: `int` has no built-in precision. I cannot reproduce, but this could be a platform-specific issue (32-bit floats?). What does `x` and `df` contain *before* you try to convert the values to integers?

Comment: Try `df.pol_number = df.pol_number.astype('int64')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using int64:

```
import pandas as pd
x = [56668772800.0, 55899926600.0, 55038007900.0, 58073681300.0, 58224458500.0]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["pol_number"])
df.pol_number = df.pol_number.astype('int64')
df
```

Output:

```
    pol_number
0  56668772800
1  55899926600
2  55038007900
3  58073681300
4  58224458500
```

Comment: Thanks - that was really quick to sort out! I tried `astype(int64)` (ie without quotes) and it didn't work. For some reason `astype(int)` and `astype('int')` both work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use numpy instead of regular Python integers, since numpy has a wider range of data types, including int64, which can represent large integers:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

x = [56668772800, 55899926600, 55038007900, 58073681300, 58224458500]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(x, dtype=np.int64), columns=["pol_number"])
print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is useful info.